# Why resource files are not refreshed after HTML5 offline manifest file was changed and swapCache method was called

Tags: html, caching, google-chrome, manifest, offline

I'm testing offline web application in chrome 14. and listed some resource files in manifest such as:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#version 1
./img/BG.jpg
./img/BtnDisable.gif
./img/BtnDown.gif
./img/BtnUp.gif
```

and after cache is loaded I replaced the "./img/BG.jpg" file to a new image, then changed the version of manifest file to 2, and finally refreshed page.

from the console, I can see "onprogress" event is triggered for each resource and finally "updateready" event is triggered. I called swapCache method in the listener of "updateready".

But after that , when I try to access "BG.jpg" in an Image tag or directly input it's URL in the address bar. the Image is still old "BG.jpg".

And I also found this issue in Safari 5.1. My web container is apache tomcat 7.

Do I misunderstand the offline mechanism and made some mistakes?

So How can I update the cached files of the client browser?

Comment: What expiry headers are you sending with your JPG and GIF files?

Comment: Server Apache-Coyote/1.1
Accept-Ranges bytes
Etag W/"212678-1319385602072"
Last-Modified Sun, 23 Oct 2011 16:00:02 GMT
Content-Type image/jpeg
Content-Length 212678
Date Mon, 24 Oct 2011 13:29:39 GMT

Comment: So, to answer my question: none?  Try setting some expiry headers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#version 2
./img/BG.jpg?v=2
./img/BtnDisable.gif?v=2
./img/BtnDown.gif?v=2
./img/BtnUp.gif?v=2
```